# Polymer: How to watch for change in <content> properties

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, content-tag

I'm just starting to learn Polymer. Here is a generic version of my polymer element:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <style>
        :host {
            position:absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        </style>
        <p>my element</p>
        <content id="first-in"></content>
        <content id="second-in"></content>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
        domReady: function() {
            alert(this.children[0].getAttribute('title')); 
            //this returns the value I want to observe
        }
    });
    </script>
<polymer-element>
```

The content tags are both being filled with another custom element (again slightly simplified):

```
<polymer-element name="in-element" attributes="title">
    <template>
        <style>
        ...
        </style>
        <p>{{title}}</p>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('in-element', {
        title: 'me'
    });
    </script>
<polymer-element>
```

What I want to be able to do is call a function in my-element when the title attribute in (any) in-element (put in the content tag) is changed (by a click event or whatever). I'm not sure how to access this using observe or if I need to use mutationObserver, etc. How is this done/Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Native properties like `title` are not observable by Polymer's data-binding system (e.g. `Object.observe()` [[info](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/90#issuecomment-19845774)]). It's generally a good idea to **avoid them**.

In your example, I've changed `title` to `mytitle` and published it with `reflect: true` so the property value reflects back to the attribute. This way you can completely avoid `.getAttribute()` and just check `.mytitle` on in-elements. You can also use `{{mytitle}}` in bindings.

You can do this through mutation observers [[1](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#mutationlightdom)]. Polymer provides `onMutation` to monitor children but you want to monitor attributes of children. For that, you need a pure MO:

```
ready: function() {
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(m) {
      if (m.target.localName == 'in-element') { // only care about in-element
        console.log(m.attributeName, m.oldValue, m.target.mytitle);
      }
    });  
  });
  // Observe attribute changes to child elements
  observer.observe(this, {
    attributes: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeOldValue: true
  }); 
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/doxafewo/1/edit

In `domReady()`, I also changed your alert of `this.children[0]` to `this.$.firstin.getDistributedNodes()[0].mytitle`. Using `getDistributedNodes()` is better because you're guaranteed to have the nodes that are actually passing through the `<content>` insertion point [[2](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#accessContentDOM)].

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Although, I'd like to call a custom function in my-element (called 'recalculate') during the mutations.forEach(). The function call works in ready() but not during the forEach(). How would I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you're forgetting to `bind(this)`. `mutations.forEach(function(m) {...}.bind(this));`

Comment: You were right about the bind. That fixed things and allowed me to call the right function. But within the function I could no longer use `getDistributedNodes()`.However, I was able to use `this.children` to get the value I wanted. Is that the correct usage of `this.children`?

Comment: I'd have to see what you're doing, but it's probably another case where you need a `.bind(this)` on the function. JS scoping is fun!

Answer (score -1):

For every attribute there is a watcher. So in your case it should be looking like this. Although there are 2 different implementation, one with attribute name as the first argument of the function.

```
Polymer('in-element', {
    title: 'me',
    titleChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

[Polymer change watchers](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#change-watchers)

Comment: Native properties like `title` are not observable by Polymer's data-binding system (e.g. `Object.observe()`). See https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/90#issuecomment-19845774

Comment: Shall be a better warning from Polymer error handling system on things like this(properties not supported). I think id is another one.